# Why a stalk of a sheaf inherits the structre of the preseaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Let $\mathcal F$ be a presheaf of a topological space $X$ of let's say a category $\mathcal C$.

i.e. $$\mathcal F:Open(X)^{op}\to \mathcal C$$

sends $$U\subseteq X\mapsto \mathcal F(U)$$

let's say $$\mathcal C = \mathcal{Ring}$$

Now a stalk of $\mathcal F$ at $a\in X$ is

$$\mathcal F_a=\{(U,\phi) \quad|\quad U\subset X \quad -open, \;\; a\in U \quad \phi\in \mathcal F(U)\}/\sim$$

$(U,\phi)\sim (U',\phi ')$ iff there exists $V\subset U\cap U'$ so that $\phi|_V=\phi'|_V$

they say this stalk inherits the structre of $\mathcal C$ in that case rings, but I am having hard time to show $\mathcal {F_a}$ is a ring?

Edit:(Attempts):

For a ring, how can I define multiplication for example? we have open sets in our doubles (U,f),  I dont see a way to define $(U,f)*(V,g)=(W,h)$
?

Comment: You say you're having a hard time - can you add your attempts to the post?

Comment: Could you do it if $U=V$?

Comment: For the sake of precision: in general, the stalk of a (pre)sheaf on $X$ with values in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is defined as a certain filtered colimit in $\mathcal{C}$. The description you give of it as a set and the claim it "inherits structure" only make sense when $\mathcal{C}$ is a concrete category and the forgetful functor to $\mathbf{Set}$ preserves filtered colimits.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you have to define $[(U,f)]*[(V,g)]$, not $(U,f)*(V,g)$, because you are working with equivalence classes. So have to take an open set $W\subseteq U\cap V$ and define
$$
[(U,f)]*[(V,g)]=[(W,f|_W)]*[(W,g|_W)]:=[(W,f|_W*g|_W)].
$$

That is, you take representatives in such a way that they share a common domain, and then you can use the know operation.